# LuaLaTeX and MetaPost

Tags: luatex, context, metapost

Is there a LuaLaTeX equivalent of

```
\startMPinclusions 
    input mpfile; 
\stopMPincusions
```

in ConTeXt?

That is, if I have

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

Some MP code that requires a reference to another File.mp

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

How do I get LuaLaTeX to recognise the other File.mp?

Answer (score 8):

I have no problem with

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}
foo

\begin{mplibcode}
input demo.mp;
\end{mplibcode}

bar
\end{document}
```

and a `demo.mp` with

```
beginfig(1);
    pair A, B, C;
    A:=(0,0); B:=(1cm,0); C:=(0,1cm);
    draw A--B--C;
\endfig;
```

[image]

Comment: The code in `\startMPinclusions` in included in all metapost environments such as `\startMPcode`, `\startMPpage`, `\startuseMPgraphics`, etc. Is that also true for `mplibcode`?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any equivalent of `\startMPinclusions` in luamplib yet. But the new maintainer of luamplib — Kim Dohyun — seems to be very active, so we may hope for it in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Just to mention that `luamplib`, thanks to Kim Dohyun, has just got an equivalent of `\startMPinclusions…\stopMPinclusions`in its latest version (2.3): the commands `\everymplib{…}`and `\everyendmplib{…}` (inspired by the `everymp`key option of Enrico Gregorio's `gmp`package).

The command `\everymplib`adds its content to the beginning of each `mplibcode`environments, and `\everyendmplib`acts similarly for the end of those environments. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{input mpcolornames; beginfig(1);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mplibcode}
        fill fullcircle scaled 2cm withcolor Pink;
    \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image: A pink-coloured disk]